# How to change the text color in WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: html, wysiwyg, text-editor

I am using **WYSIWYG** text editor in admin control panel.I want to know how can I change the color of a text using this editor.How i can do that?

Comment: at-least tell us which editor. when asking question, i don't know why people think every other person in the world know what is in asker's mind and what they are doing.

Comment: in `CKEditor` you have to enable `Text Color` and `Background Color` buttons or change tool bar option to `Full Toolbar`

Comment: i have enabled the text color and background color in config.js like this:-
config.colorButton_enableMore = true ;
 config.colorButton_colors = '000000,feb71a,705e5f,95703c,7e4a5e,8b5543,6d715a,5c6e76' ;
 config.colorButton_colors2 = 'ffffff,e6e6e6,f6f6f6,e8dadc,f8d273,f3f9e3,fbeabe,f4f8db,FFFF00' ;

still its not showing me any change in the editor

Answer (score 1):

to enable color buttons you have to add the following to the `config.toolbar`

```
{ name: 'colors', items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] },
```

check [CKEditor Toolbar](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if your WYSIWYG has color formating you can use it.
If not that I consider so, every WYSIWYG editor has a source view that you can edit source and then with inline styling you can color your text
I've used TinyMCE and I've done this like this

```
<div>
<p style="text-align: center; color: red;">saasdasddd</p>
</div>
```

not my text color is red

Answer (score 0):

```html
   
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
 add this li
    <li><div class="wysihtml5-colors" data-wysihtml5-command-value="orange"></div><a class="wysihtml5-colors-title" data-wysihtml5-command="foreColor" data-wysihtml5-command-value="orange">' + k((g = b && b.locale, g = null == g || g === !1 ? g : g.colours, g = null == g || g === !1 ? g : g.orange, typeof g === j ? g.apply(b) : g)) + "</a></li>\n

<!-- end snippet -->
```